# Trigger to Update Contact Email Address on Asset Custom Field

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm having trouble with a trigger that needs to update my custom email field on Asset with the email address from Contact that is a lookup field.  The code I have is below and I can't figure out why it's not working:

```
trigger UpdateContactEmail on Asset (before insert, before update) {

 Set<Id> assetContactEmail = new Set<Id>();
 for(Asset record : trigger.new)
    assetContactEmail.add(record.ContactEmail__c);
 Map<Id, Contact> contactEmail = new Map<Id, Contact>([Select ID, Email 
                                             FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :AssetContactEmail]);

 for (Asset a : Trigger.new){

  Contact c = contactEmail.get(a.ContactEmail__c);

  if (c !=null) {
    a.ContactEmail__c = c.Email
  }
 }        
}
```

Comment: do you have other triggers on `Asset` that might be undoing the work of this one. Trigger order of execution is undefined

Comment: Is ContactEmail__c a lookup field? That's an unfortunate field name for a lookup.

Comment: I don't have any triggers that would undo the work.  Contact Email is a text field which this trigger is supposed to populate.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Replace the line `assetContactEmail.add(record.ContactEmail__c);`
with **`assetContactEmail.add(record.ContactId);`**

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this didn't fix it.  The record I need on my object (Asset) is the associated Contact Email Address and I update the Contact on the Asset via lookup field.  So I need the trigger to fire when the contact is updated or when the asset record is created.

Answer (score 0):

There must be two custom fields on Asset, one will be lookup to Contact and other one to hold the value of the email field from Contact.
Currently, you are having only one lookup field and in your above code, you are trying to update same lookup field with email field which would not work.
Create, one more email field on Asset to hold the Contact Email, and make the below changes in your code 
Replace

```
a.ContactEmail__c = c.Email
```

with

```
a.NewEmailFieldOnAsset__c = c.Email
```

Also, you will need to write after update trigger on Contact as well, to copy the updated Email value on Contact to all its related Assets.

**Note :** You can create a simple formula field for Contact's email on Asset which will serve your purpose and there will be no need for trigger on both the objects (Asset and Contact). And your formula for new formula field should look something like this

```
ContactEmail__r.Email
```